# ajax-email already exist..still form is submitting. :(

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to prevent form from submitting..iff email is already exist..
i am using hidden variable''
my code..

```
$.ajax({
     url: link_url,
    type: "post", //post is more secure
    data: JSON.stringify(senddata), // JSON is format
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, // for @ space and all
    success: function(result){
        if(result > 0){
            document.getElementById("email_valid").className = "error";
            document.getElementById('email_valid').innerHTML='Email already exist.';
            var res=document.getElementById("dnsub").value;
            if(res>0) {
                flag=false;
            }
            else{flag=true;}

        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("email_valid").className = "success";
            document.getElementById('email_valid').innerHTML='Available';
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
})
```

its my ajax code
how to use hidden variable..

Comment: `document.getElementById("dnsub").value` what is the value in it? and where are you submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are checking email address is exists on form submission.

Instead of that, Change the input type as "Submit" into "button".

For that button, write an event as on click. In Onclick of button check the email address is exists.

If its exists show an error message to the user, else trigger form submit event.

```
$("form").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to prevent the default form submission first. And then submit the form in the `success` handler of your ajax call.

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent form submission
  $.ajax({
     url: link_url,
     type: "post", //post is more secure
     data: JSON.stringify(senddata), // JSON is format
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, // for @ space and all
     context: this, // pointing to form submit
     success: function(result){
        if(result > 0){
            document.getElementById("email_valid").className = "error";
            document.getElementById('email_valid').innerHTML='Email already exist.';
            var res=document.getElementById("dnsub").value;   
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("email_valid").className = "success";
            document.getElementById('email_valid').innerHTML='Available';
            // the above two lines will be moot as the form will submit and page will get refreshed
            this.submit(); // all good, submit the form
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
  });

});
```